# How to find the cause of a RollbackException?

Tags: java, jpa

I am working on a project where I have an RMI-based marketplace and I am adding a database to save datas from the market.

When I am trying to put an "item" on sale from a client, I call the remote method called "putItemOnSale" from the "market" (server) and I get a javax.persistence.RollbackException. Here is the code of the concerned method and the item class :

```
@Override
public void putItemOnSale(String name, String trader, Float price) throws RemoteException, RejectedException {
    EntityTransaction transaction = null;
    try {
        transaction = beginTransaction();
        List<ItemImpl> existingItems = em.createNamedQuery("findItemsWithName", ItemImpl.class).
                setParameter("name", name).getResultList();
        if (!existingItems.isEmpty()) {
            // item already existing, error
            throw new RejectedException("Rejected: Item with name : " + name + " already exists");
        }
        List<TraderImpl> existingTraders = em.createNamedQuery("findTraderWithName",TraderImpl.class).
                setParameter("ownername",trader).getResultList();

        if (existingTraders.isEmpty()){
            throw new RejectedException("Rejected : Trader not registered");
        }

        // create Item.
        ItemImpl item = new ItemImpl(name,existingTraders.get(0),price);
        em.persist(item);

    } 
    finally {
        commitTransaction(transaction);
    }
}
```

Item class :

```
public class ItemImpl extends UnicastRemoteObject implements Item, Serializable 
{
    @Id
    @Column( name = "id", nullable = false )
    @GeneratedValue( strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE )
    private long ItemId;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @ManyToOne
    private TraderImpl owner;

    @Column(name = "price")
    private Float price;
...
}
```

Before trying to sell an item, I manage to register a trader from the client and it is added to the database without any exception. Here is the full stacktrace of the exception I get, it is not really explicit to me. Does anyone have an idea on how to find why this exception happens ?
I tried to add a breakpoint to see more precisely where the problem comes from, but the exception happens as soon as I try to step into the PutItemOnSale method...

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" javax.persistence.RollbackException: Transaction rolled back because transaction was set to RollbackOnly.
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.transaction.EntityTransactionImpl.commit(EntityTransactionImpl.java:141)
    at marketplace.MarketPlaceImpl.commitTransaction(MarketPlaceImpl.java:351)
    at marketplace.MarketPlaceImpl.putItemOnSale(MarketPlaceImpl.java:181)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:322)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:177)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:174)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:173)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:553)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:808)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:667)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
    at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.exceptionReceivedFromServer(StreamRemoteCall.java:273)
    at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.executeCall(StreamRemoteCall.java:251)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(UnicastRef.java:160)
    at java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invokeRemoteMethod(RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.java:194)
    at java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.java:148)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy6.putItemOnSale(Unknown Source)
    at client.ClientForm.sellButtonActionPerformed(ClientForm.java:1007)
    at client.ClientForm.access$200(ClientForm.java:31)
    at client.ClientForm$4.actionPerformed(ClientForm.java:321)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6505)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6270)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:729)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:688)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:686)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:702)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:700)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:699)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
```

Comment: RMI doesn't really have anything to do with this.

Comment: You should avoid float and double. And now that you speak of RMI, you should probably google the Java keyword "strictfp".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note how you commit the transaction in the finally clause (assuming that the commitTransaction() method is not really poorly named): that means your code will attempt to ALWAYS commit the transaction, even when an exception happens and the transaction should be rolled back.

So your real problem is: you are tripping an exception inside a finally clause which is the result of an earlier exception, thus making the earlier exception invisible.

You should probably add a check to that commitTransaction() method to see if the transaction is marked for rollback - and if so, do a rollback rather than a commit.